# Is the scientific explanation behind Smartkleen legit?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm trying to have a conversation/debate about the SmartKleen laundry detergent alternative, but lack the knowledge to understand if their [explanation](http://www.smartklean.com/html/science.html) is science or pseudoscience.

Far Infrared emission at cold water temp, smaller water molecule clusters, magnets that increase levels of dissolved oxygen, etc., can someone offer a solid critique?

Comment: Take several wiki articles, shake the sentences randomly, and, voila, Smartkleen science! Not about to waste time on woo-woo.

Comment: It suffices to say that I was originally interested in answering this, but reading that page made my head hurt.

Comment: @chipbuster Agreed! To me, it's marketing technobabble that you would use to sell penny stocks for a perpetuum motion company that also offers remote healing and time travel :D

Comment: These guys are good. They even tell you to ignore claims that their product doesn't work!

Just check http://www.smartklean.com/html/wikipedia.html out and the subsequent wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laundry_ball) if you want an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of "smaller water clusters" penetrating the cloth more efficiently is actually quite smart as the same idea is utilised in steam cleaners. But the rest of the article is a bit too psychotic. How can they say that colours are preserved while the Ball constantly generates H$_2$O$_2$ (in every second)? And why do they recommend the Stain Remover for stains if the ball was such a miracle...

Answer (score 0):

Do a wash without adding anything.  Given lightly soiled fabric, there is enough detergent residue to get things "sparkling chean."  Absence of perfume will give a nice linen scent.  Water soluble dirt does not need detergent to disappear.  HOWEVER, oily stuff will stay put and accumulate. Things likes starch and protein generally adhere and accumulate.

A laundry ball is nonsense no matter what its claimed mechanism.  A nasty accumulation of crud requires weeks or months to accumulate.  The laundry ball "wears out."